# Problema al exportar a excel en el servidor

Tags: php, excel

Tengo el siguiente problema tengo un archivo `php` que exporto a excel y lo descarga automáticamente pero solo me funciona de forma local, si lo subo al servidor solo se abre como una pagina cualquiera. Que puede ser?

```
<?php 
include_once 'clases/clase_pedidos.php';
    error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
   session_start();
   if (!isset($_SESSION["rut"]) || empty($_SESSION["rut"]) ||            $_SESSION["perfil"]==2) {
   header("location: login.php");
}

$obj= new Pedido();

        $obj->id_activo="si";
        $obj->id_venado=$_GET["id_venado"];
        $obj->fecha_1=$_GET["fecha_1"];
        $obj->fecha_2=$_GET["fecha_2"];
        $obj->fecha_venado1= $_GET["fecha_venado1"];
        $obj->fecha_venado2=$_GET["fecha_venado2"];
        $tabla=$obj->lista_compra_fecha();
        $obj->excel="si";
        $tabla_cliente=$obj->lista_cliente_fecha();
        date_default_timezone_set("America/Santiago");
        $fecha = date("Y-m-d ");
header('Pragma: public'); 
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past    
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); 
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1 
header('Cache-Control: pre-check=0, post-check=0, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1 
header('Pragma: no-cache'); 
header('Expires: 0'); 
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: none'); 
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); // This should work for IE & Opera 
header('Content-type: application/x-msexcel'); // This should work for the rest 
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;    filename="pedido_rango_fecha'.$fecha.'.xls"');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

saque algunos headers y funciono los dejo aqui por si alguien tiene el mismo problema

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); 

header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="pedido_.xls");

header('Pragma: no-cache'); 

header('Expires: 0');
```

Comment: podrías poner como solucionado. gracias